# lua code fails on require statement

Tags: module, lua, include

**Problem Description**

I have some code that I've inherited and I'm trying to debug.  It's a web application that is written in lua for the back end. 
The system fails right now with an error that says the following:

> 398: attempt to call global 'require' (a nil value)

**Code**

Line 398 is the require statement you see below..

```
getstatus = function()
        require("processinfo")
        local value,errtxt=processinfo.package_version(packagename)
        etc...
```

**What I've tried so far:**

1. I've tried to test to make sure that the package / module it's looking for exists.  It does. It's in my lua lib folder

   test-dev:/usr/share# find / -name processinfo*

   /usr/share/lua/5.1/processinfo.lua
2. I've also launched the lua command line and tried to include the module, like so:

   test-dev:/usr/share# lua
    Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio

   > require("processinfo")

And it seems to be happy, no error messages.

3. Finally, I've tried to move the require statement from line 398 to the top of the file with the rest of the include statements that I have ... like so:

   module(..., package.seeall)
   posix = require("posix")
   utils = require("utils")
   processinfo = require("processinfo")

When I do that, the error message about the require statement goes away but instead i get an error about the string function I'm calling.  The error message is :

```
139: attempt to index global 'string' (a nil value)
```

Line 139 is the opening of a while loop that looks like this:

```
while string.find(result, "%$[%w_]+") do
    -- do something
end
```

**Additional Information**

- Lua version is 5.1
- this code is working on another server...

Comment: Have you opened the string library? Try `require("string")`.
By default none of the libraries (debug, string, math ..) are not opened/required and must be either hardcoded to be opened or opened by the user with require.

Comment: @Rochet2 "By default" is a complicated statement in lua. In the default interpreter (and default library usage) the default modules **are** available without being loaded. But that's not true (necessarily) for other environments.

Comment: Did you write the code that used `require` and `string` that is causing problems? Does the code use `module` or `setfenv` in it after the initial `require` calls? Does it use `local shortname = library.name` a lot near the top? This looks like you are trying to use default globals once the module environment table has been replaced.

Comment: @Rochet2, I'm  used to having the default libs like "string" available without explicitly including them.  However, I did add a line to include the string lib and the table lib.  It seems I'm getting further along... but i am having to manually add these libs.  If we normally don't have to do this on other servers running similar apps, what could be the root cause do you think?

Comment: @EtanReisner, no the code was already there.  it uses module(...,package.seeall) at the top of the file.  I'm thinking it has something to do with this??

Comment: @EtanReisner since this code is working on a different server, i'm thinking i should be able to compare to see what's different about them.  But what specific things pertaining to lua libs should i check?

Comment: `package.seeall` prevents the default globals from disappearing (and is fairly ugly). But that should mean you can use `require` and `string` normally in the module code. Check the versions of lua and the applications on both servers very carefully to make sure they are actually the same and that the exact code that is failing here is working there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99734/discussion-between-dot-and-etan-reisner).